# Why doesn't Android allow installation of drivers like Windows and Linux does?

Tags: linux, windows, drivers, android, updates

We are all aware of Android's weakest point: Devices get updated to the latest version of Android months after it is released to AOSP, and in most cases they don't get updated at all. The main source for this problem is the wide variety of devices that run the OS. But, Windows and Linux have the same wide range of hardware to support; yet, I don't have to wait for HP to release a Windows update for my desktop PC. I just download Windows, install it, and then put in any drivers I need.


Why can't I do the same with Android. Wouldn't this problem be solved if in Android you could install manufacturer drivers the same way you do on Windows or Linux.

Comment: Because ARM drivers are handed entirely differently.

Comment: Because device manufacturers seem to be against it, they do everything they can to prevent you from installing custom firmware or gaining root access on the device, so why would they openly provide drivers for the hardware in their phones ?

Comment: solving this problem would unleash a wave of malware and phone hacking like none ever seen. Attackers would be able to install undetectable malware that likely could persist even between system flashes. Additionally linux and android drivers must be written and built for the specific kernel revision they target, making it a nightmare for device manufacturers. Don't think of android like you do a general purpose OS. they are very very very different animals.

Comment: @FrankThomas Wouldn't all of that also apply to general purpose operating systems?

Comment: @YasmaniLlanes, in fact it does. Most Rootkits are kernel level phenomenon. That is why essentially all OSs require Root access to install drivers and kernel modules. The differance here however, is that PC driver installs are a necessary evil, since the hardware base is very diverse. With phones, since the hardware and software are under the OEMs control, and not user-servicable, they have the option to lock them out. Also note that most phone users do not have root access, to prevent the apps they use from having root. and finally note that many phone users are not terribly savvy.

Comment: The guy (random) who close this interesting question should be banned. On Stack you get hundred little chiefs abusing their power, for a single interesting question/answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are a lot of reasons actually. It's a lot easier to damage an ARM device, so most manufacturers keep it closed. It's really the same thing with Apple, actually. You would have to root your Android in order to mess with it a little bit more.

Also, warranties with phones/tablets are different than warranties with computers.